# Store not getting loaded

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2

I am using Sencha V2. I am trying to populate my list with the values in a Users.json file.

The code in my list file is

```
Ext.define('iPolis.view.personlist',{
    extend:'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'personlist',
    requires: [
        'Ext.List',
        'Ext.form.FieldSet',
        'Ext.Button'

    ],

    config: {
              fullscreen:true,
              items: [
                       {
                         xtype:'toolbar',
                         docked:'top',
                         title:'iPolis',
                          items:[
                                      {
                                          ui:'back',
                                           icon:'home',
                                           iconCls:'home',
                                           iconMask:true,
                                            id: 'homebtn',
                                            handler:function ()
                                                   {
                                                    }
                                      },

                          ]
                       },

                         {
                    xtype : 'list',
                    store : 'personListStore',
                    itemTpl : '<div class="contact">HI <br/> {name}</div>'

                        }
                    }
              ]

    }
});
```

and the store is calling the file using:

```
 Ext.define('iPolis.store.personListStore', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
storeId:'personListStore',
            model : 'iPolis.model.personListModel',

            proxy : {
                type : 'ajax',
                url : '/users.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'users'
                }
            },
             autoLoad: true
    });
```

The code for my json file is:

```
{
    "users": [
       {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Ed Spencer",
           "email": "ed@sencha.com"
       },
       {
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Abe Elias",
           "email": "abe@sencha.com"
       }
    ]
}
```

I am gettin a blank screen. I have tried everything but no data is displayed on the screen.

Comment: First, `console.log(yourStore.getRange())` to ensure that your store actually got data from json file. Second, please paste here the code of your json file, model file as well and I'll help you debug this.'

Comment: @Thiem: I have edited the code and added the json file. The json data is not being loaded in my list. Anything that am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.define('iPolis.store.personListStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config:{
    model : 'iPolis.model.personListModel',
    storeId:'personListStore',
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : '/users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'users'
        }
    },
     autoLoad: true  }  });
```

try this may help you.

Comment: nope. dint work. i tried using dummy data to populate my list, but even that dint work. So am guessing there is a problem with my logic with the list and store.

Comment: add storeId in store and give it in list as store some time it work for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, for the code -> "itemTpl : '<div class="contact">HI {name}{</div>'" I got a one line response of "HI" with no name taken from the json file. It gave me an error saying "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/TFS/iPolis/app/model/data/users.json?_dc=1334561794830&page=1&start=0&limit=25. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: This error because of wrong store url so give relative path to json file in store url..

Comment: i gave the url as "url: 'app/model/data/skeletons.json',"  It still doesn work.

Comment: I loaded the app onto the server and got rid of the error but i still dont get the data from the json file onto the list. I get a warning that says "Attempting to create a DataView with a layout. DataViews do not have a layout configuration as their items are laid out automatically.". If i remove the layout attribute, i dont get any output at al.

Comment: Are you able to get the data stored on the json file loaded onto the list?? i get only one item in the list that says "Hello null".

Comment: hey, it worked for me after i removed the root: users from the json file as well as the store and made it into an array. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In your list the store is `personStore` but your trying to use `personListStore`.

Comment: i have used personListStore everywhere. M sorry for the confusion. I was tryin to create an object of the store class and use it instead. personListStore doesn work.